# Stackdriver JVM monitoring in Google Container Engine (Kubernetes)

Tags: java, jvm, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver

I've read the docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/plugins/jvm) regarding standalone JVM monitoring with stackdriver (so that one can get GC insights etc), but how do one enable this in a good way when running on Google Container Engine? We're running multiple JVM's in Docker on the same machine in Kubernetes so we'd like the Stackdriver agent to connect to each one and not just the one specified by the `JMX_PORT` environment variable.

Comment: I also have the same question. Due to Stackdriver's current instance-centric design, the way I see it it's currently not possible without some very heavy script-fu.

Comment: I found this one: https://hub.docker.com/r/wikiwi/stackdriver-agent/. I am testing it and I will let you know!

Comment: Have you had a chance to try it yet? Did it work?